# Cygwin X11 forwarding using Xming

Tags: ssh, cygwin, x11, x11-forwarding

i am connected with cygwin to a ssh server

there i want to open a application via x11-forwarding

i use xming as x11 server on my windows machine

now in putty i had the possibility to automatically forward x11 and so i dont need to export my DISPLAY, thats not a problem i can set it every time i connect to the server.

but if i export my DISPLAY, it wont start the application it always says:

```
Error: Can't open display: xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

i really liked the way putty worked and want to user cygwin.

i tried Cygwin/X but there always opens another terminal which i dont really like. i like to open my application from my existing standart cygwin terminal where i also connect to the server

is there any way doing this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i startet the xserver with the following command and after that i could start the programms automatically on my remote ssh server and it was forwarded automatically to my xserver

```
startxwin -- -listen tcp &
```

after this i even didnt have to set the DISPLAY